# What happens in Django when primary_key default has a collision?

Tags: django, encryption, django-models, primary-key

If I had a field in the model that has primary_key=True and a default function that can return ids with collisions, what happens on save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as with any other unique constraint: the database would refuse to insert the new record, and Django would report an `IntegrityError`.

Which is why you should always use an autoincrementing integer field for your primary key, which is what the default `id` field does anyway.